# getting last modified time in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a datetime column in sql2005. it's default value is getdate().
How can I update it's value automatically when others value update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a trigger on the table!

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateDate
ON dbo.Table
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
UPDATE Table
SET ModifiedDate = GetDate() -- or sysdatetimeoffset()
where table.Id = inserted.Id
```

Comment: The trigger is ok but remove the "GO" between "AFTER UPDATE AS" and "UPDATE".  And the comments in SQL Server are with -- not with //

Answer (score 2):

You can use timestamp variable, basicly it updates itself everytime the row is changed and you can have only one timestamp variable per specific table.

Take a look at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: The "timestamp" data type in Microsoft SQL Server is not actually related to dates or times.  It represents a 32bit binary identifier that is unique across all tables in a database.  Converting it to a datetime data type will not give you a valid result.

Comment: John, you got that right but still this type could help you to keep up with record update and essentially it can help you with data caching.

Answer (score 1):

[You can make a trigger for this](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i), but depending on how often you update it could be cumbersome.

Are most of your updates batch updates or individual records?  Is it ad-hoc or done through a stored proc?  If it is a stored proc and/or batch updates, it may be more performant to declare a variable for the current datetime, and use that to update this value.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a trigger.

After update, set this value to getdate(). I currently can't find some articles about the syntax, but I'm sure you can do better ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is base of SilverSkin answer. I just update his statement to include the necessary JOIN.

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateDate
ON dbo.Table
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
UPDATE Table
SET ModifiedDate = GetDate() -- or sysdatetimeoffset()
JOIN Table t JOIN Inserted i ON t.Id = i.Id
```

This is a syntax for SQL Server 2005.